# Product price is showing on front end

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using this code to show the releated product on the page

```
<?php 
$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds(); ?>


         <div class="scroll-pane" style="height:350px;">
    <ol class="mini-products-list " id="block-related">
    <?php foreach($related_prods as $related):
    $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related); ?>
        <li class="item">

            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(84, 81) ?>" width="84" height="81" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo strip_tags(substr($this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()), 0, 30).'...') ?></a></p>
                    <div class="releted-product-price">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true,'-related') ?>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <label class="rel-label"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></label>

                <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
    </div> ?>
```

but product is coming and its price is not showing while I have code for price of that product.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true,'-related') ?>
```

but it is not showing the price. Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the block that uses this template extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.
Also you can use this to get the related products instead of getting the ids and then loading each product one by one (for performance reasons):

```
$product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
```